# Moving from NAnt to PowerShell. Copy/Delete replacement

Tags: powershell, nant

Please help me to translate this to PowerShell:

```
<delete>
  <fileset defaultexcludes="false" basedir="${svnRepository}">
    <include name="**/*" />
    <exclude name="**/.svn" />
    <exclude name="**/.svn/**" />
  </fileset>
</delete>

<!-- Copy entire output of successful build into the svn working folder -->
<copy todir="${svnRepository}">
  <fileset defaultexcludes="false" basedir="${binariesFolder}">
    <include name="**/*" />
    <exclude name="**/Bin/*.pdb"/>
    <exclude name="**/Bin/*.xml"/>
  </fileset>
</copy>
```

PowerShell

```
Get-ChildItem -recurse "$svnRepository" | ? {$_.FullName -notmatch '.svn'} | Remove-Item -Recurse
```

I've tried to write something like above, but it doesn't exclude all SVN directories in nested foldes, e.g if I have a directory `C:\blabla\test` with nested .svn it will ignore `C:\blabla\test\.svn\*` but at the same time it will try to remove `C:\blabla\test` itself

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you have to do anything here? `Get-ChildItem` already doesn't include hidden folders like `.svn`, `.git` etc. and only includes them when you specify the `-Force` parameter.

Comment: Yeah, but gci will also include top level folder which can be not hidden. How to deal with this?

Comment: @JohnSmith - What do you mean? The example you gave in the question is not clear.

Comment: @JohnSmith - If the $svnRepository variable is pointing to `C:\blabla\test`, it will not remove `C:\blabla\test`